# Removing Java Convenience Event Handler inside itself

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

Working with event handlers in java, there are cases when you would want to remove an event handler. There can be a few approaches for doing that like creating a reference to that and then using the `addEventHandler()` and `removeEventHandler()` by passing the event type and it's name. I wanted to ask if this approach is valid for unregistering an event handler inside itself after the logic is executed

(for example if i'm using JavaFX)

```
node.setOnAction(event -> {

// logic goes here...

node.setOnAction(null);
});
```

Will this work fine or is it wrong ?

Comment: what happened when you tried it ;) Null is the default value for the handler, so it's fine to reset to null. Please don't post code that's written on-the-fly, always type into your IDE and c&p (prevents spelling errors like the above)

Comment: I debugged it by printing a message to console in the event. The message got printed only once and did not repeat meaning that the event got unregistered. My question was just to make sure that it is okay to do this inside the handler and if it's not a bad practice. Thanks anyways.